TImeLineVIew is not updating inside ViewModifier for metal shaders in swiftUI
Recently I came across metal shaders in swiftUI, which is interesting. So I started my journey in it.
I want to create hue effect using metal shaders and also i want to write the code clean.
Here's my code
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var start = Date.now
    @State private var touch: CGPoint = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .metalModifier(type: .rainbow)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

enum MetalFunctions {
   case rainbow
}

struct MyCustomModifiers: ViewModifier {
    var metalType: MetalFunctions
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View { 
    
       switch metalType { 
          case .rainbow:
            TimelineView(.animation) { timeLine in
                let time = Date.now.distance(to: timeLine.date)
                content
                    .colorEffect(ShaderLibrary.rainbow(.float(time)))
            }
          default: content 
       }
    }
}

extension View {
    func metalModifier(type: MetalFunctions) -> some View {
        modifier(MyCustomModifiers(metalType: type))
    }
}

Here is my metal function
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <SwiftUI/SwiftUI_Metal.h>
using namespace metal;

/// Continous changign colors moving
[[ stitchable ]] half4 rainbow(float2 position, half4 color, float time) {
    float angle = atan2(position.y, position.x) + time;
    
    return half4(sin(angle), sin(angle + 2), sin(angle + 4), color.a);
}

I know if I place TimeLineView inside body it is working.
Note: Please focus on why it is not working
